# Trying to change how the remove button works

Tags: php

Below snippet code is to remove the item from the cart. It will remove the item when user put 0 in the text field and then click the update button(submit). My request is how can I changes the code that the button will remove the item without make sure user enter 0 in the text field. I'm new to PHP. I hope you can help me. Thank you.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!empty($_SESSION['cart'])){
    foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $key => $val){
        if($val==0){
            unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
        }else{
            $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['quantity']=$val;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

html code :

```
     <td><input type="text" name="quantity[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]" 
      size="6" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id']]['quantity'];  
     ?>"> </td>


    <button type="submit" name="submit">Update Cart</button>
```

add item process

```
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo "$" . $row['price']; ?></td>
    <td><a href="index.php?page=product&action=add&id=<?php echo $row['id']; 
    ?>">Add to Cart</a></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Need more information. Can you share the html form, please ?

Comment: check my updates :) @JazZ

Comment: So you want to remove all items from the cart when the form is submited ?

Comment: no. just the chosen item @JazZ

Comment: There are different ways you could implement this. One common one is to have a "delete" button for each item in the cart to delete that very item. Another approach is to show a "delete" column in a table showing the cart where each item has a checkbox in that column. The user can check the checkboxes and then press update to delete those items. Which way do you want to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guest you have a table of products where you can set quantity for each products and on the right of each row, a button "Update Cart".

When you press that button, you want to remove the product from that row, isn't it ? So the button must be called "Remove" or similar even if it updates the cart items quantity in the same time. It  will be clearer for users.

After that, to remove the product when you press its remove button, you'll need to get the id of that product to know which product you have to remove.

Here we go :

#### HTML

```
<td>
    <input type="text" name="quantity[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]" size="6" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id']]['quantity'];?>">
</td>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Remove</button>
```

Note that we added the `$row['id']` as the submit button value.

#### PHP

Now we have to say that we want to remove the item from the cart for the item that has the same `id` as the submit value :

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (!empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['quantity'] as $key => $val) {
            if ($key == $_POST['submit']) { // Here we check if ID is the same
                unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
            } else { 
                $integervalue = intval($val);
                if ($integervalue <=0) { // Then we use the NineBerry integer check. So if item quantity is 0 or is invalid, we remove that item from the cart
                    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
                } else { // we update other products quantities
                    $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['quantity']=$integervalue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's still a good idea to check whether $val is a valid integer value before storing it in the session as the quantity. If it is not, also remove the item or at least use the previous quantity. (i.e. don't assign it)

Comment: I agree. Updated my answer to add your integer check.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to remove all items that do not have a valid positive number in the quantity field.

To do this, use `intval` to explicitly convert the entered string to an integer. This will be 0, when the string does not represent a valid integer. Then check the result is a positive number.

```
foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $key => $val)
{
    $integervalue = intval($val);
    if($integervalue <=0)
    {
        unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['quantity']=$integervalue;
    }
}
```

Comment: @VegaMaya How would the user choose an item?

Comment: Can user choose two items to be remowed at once? @VegaMaya

Comment: @VegaMaya when updating your question please clearly state what is deserved output. Even after your update the above solution is valid one